# template with bool parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boolean

I need to implement template with bool parameter.
If bool=true, we need to use list container else we need to use vector container.

```
template <bool isList>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: As answered by MM, use `std::conidtional` or specialize template for `true` and `false`

Comment: template function or type?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have at least three ways to do it.

### i. Use [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <bool isList>
struct A
{
    typename std::conditional<isList, 
                              std::list<int>,
                              std::vector<int>>::type container;
};
```

### ii. Use [template specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) for the `bool` parameter

```
template <bool isList>
struct A;

template<>
struct A<true>
{
    std::list<int> container;
};

template<>
struct A<false>
{
    std::vector<int> container;
};
```

then

```
A<true>  a1; // container of a1 is a list
A<false> a2; // container of a2 is a vector
```

### iii. Use template functions

If you need a template function type, then you can do it like below. It returns a container based on the entry parameter.

```
template <bool isList>
auto func() -> typename std::conditional<isList, 
                                         std::list<int>,
                                         std::vector<int>>::type
{
    typename std::result_of<decltype(func<isList>)&()>::type result;

    // ...

    return result;
};
```

then

```
auto f1 = func<true>();  // f1 is a list
auto f2 = func<false>(); // f2 is a vector
```

Answer (score 13):

With c++17 onward, there are some cleaner options.

### Classes/structs

For classes, the only thing I'd suggest you do differently from masoud's answer with `std::conditional` is to use a `using` declaration instead of directly using the type when declaring the member variable. That way, the type can be re-used and the `typename` is redundant. Also, `std::conditional_t` is shorter.

Example:

```cpp
template<bool isList, typename T>
struct TemplatedStruct
{
    using Container = std::conditional_t<isList, std::list<T>, std::vector<T>>;
    Container container;
};
```

### Functions

1. Use a templated function with the `if constexpr` syntax together with `auto` return type deduction. Example:

```cpp
template<bool isList, typename T>
auto createContainer()
{
    if constexpr (isList)
    {
        return std::list<T>{};
    }
    else
    {
        return std::vector<T>{};
    }
}
```

2. Use `std::conditional` like in masoud's answer, but cleaner.
   Either:

```cpp
template<
    bool isList, typename T, 
    typename Container = std::conditional_t<isList, std::list<T>, std::vector<T>>
>
auto createContainer() -> Container
{
    Container result;
    // Do stuff that works with both containers I guess
    return result;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
template<bool isList, typename T>
auto createContainer()
{
    using Container = std::conditional_t<isList, std::list<T>, std::vector<T>>;
    Container result;
    // Do stuff that works with both containers I guess
    return result;
}
```

I removed

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>
```

from my examples for simplicity.